# Hadoop - environment setup on EC2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2

Im configuring hadoop 2.7.1 on amazon EC2 (ubuntu) and all TCP ports(0 ~ 65535) are opened.

My node structure is `nameNode, resourceManager, dataNode01, dataNode02`, and
each of those has an EC2 respectively.

Also, I made SSH connection to be possible without keypair or password.

If I type `sbin/start-all.sh` on `nameNode`, then `SecondaryNameNode, NameNode` are created on `nameNode`, `NodeManager` is created on `resourceManager, dataNode01, dataNode02`. (*Note*: `ResourceManager` is not created on `resourceManager` and there are no `DataNode`s on those.)

Why aren't `DataNode, ResourceManager` created correctly?

If I type `sbin/start-yarn.sh` on `resourceManager`, then `ResourceManager` is created. (... is that way right?)

On web `[nameNodeIP]:50070`, there are 3 dead nodes (`resourceManager:50010, dataNode01:50010, dataNode02:50010`).

#### So, how could I make `sbin/start-all.sh` works correctly?

These codes below are the configuration I did.

#### core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://nameNode:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### yarn-site

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>resourceManager</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.hosts</name>
            <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/slaves</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.1/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.1/data/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### hadoop-env.sh

```
(...omitted...)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

#### mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### slaves

```
resourceManager
dataNode01
dataNode02
```

Let me know what I should fix.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem before and resolve it by below steps.

I think your `slaves` must include `nameNode` with all other nodes.

Add it to your `slaves`

#### slaves

```
nameNode
resourceManager
dataNode01
dataNode02
```

and recreate your `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` (or `data/, data/namenode, data/datanode`) in all of your nodes

and format your namenode `hadoop namenode -format`

Lastly, do `sbin/start-all.sh`

hopefully it works